# Extra lines in ajax response wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using jQuery for ajax requests in wordpress and Success response is like

```
1. 
2.
3.<option value="65">test</option>
```

means newline character being added when the script executes. so my respionse is not getting display into html. I am using ajax into fancybox.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the response you're getting is in the var response:

```
// splitting up response line by line
var arr = response.split('\n');

// getting the last line, and then getting everything after the dot
var html = arr[arr.length-1].split('.')[1];
```

The pure HTML is now in the variable html.

Cheers

Comment: Is the response you provided the response you consistently get (at least of the same form)?

Comment: yeah everytime..with two extra line

Comment: If that's your response, my code works. It extracts that option tag from the response. What do you want?

Comment: i want to remove extra two lines before <option> tag and your code is not removing

Comment: It's not working because ajax call request is in popup and i am using fancybox